# How to retrieve a value from an php associative array

Tags: php

I have an array that shows

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [subjects_id] => 4 [0] => 4 ) [1] => Array (
>   [subjects_id] => 33 [0] => 33 ) )

All I want is the end `4` and end `33`, how do I get them?

Comment: `foreach($arr as $a){ echo $a[0]; }`? o,o

Comment: It's not that clear, but here you go : `$array[0]['subject_id']` will return 4; `$array[1]['subjects_id']` will return 33.
Note that `$array[0][0]` will also return 4 in your case...

Comment: if you dont want to use loop $arr[0][subjects_id], and $arr[1][subjects_id] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    'subjects_id' => 4, '0' => '4'
  ),
  array(
    'subjects_id' => '33', '0' => '33'
  )
);
// get the numbers...
$number = $arr[0][0]; // first one
$number2 = $arr[1][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You really could have solved that by looking at http://php.net/array

In the lack of better requirement explanation in the question itself, I'll provide general answer which might or might not be useful:

```
<?
  echo $array[0]['subjects_id'];
?>
```

and

```
<?
  echo $array[1]['subjects_id'];
?>
```

will do the trick. Also, an observation:

You shouldn't use mysql_ functions in php since they are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo. Also, if you insist on using mysql_* function use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Where in any part of the question is mysql_ mentioned?

Comment: It's not, but the provided `Array()` suggests that each element of the array is output of `mysql_fetch_array()` because `mysql_fetch_array()` gives you an array where you can acces your columns using their name or their index. Hence the same value for [0] and [subjects_id]. It is the first row of a query result. This is only my observation, it might not be correct though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I am using pdo, when I get the results of my query that array is returned and confused the hell out of me

Comment: There are probably versions of the function which you are using, but which will return either only column name, or column index, which might help clarify the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo my_array[0][0] // 4
echo my_array[1][0] // 33
```

or

```
echo my_array[0]['subject_id'] // 4
echo my_array[1]['subject_id'] // 33
```